# Get size of image after finished loading

Tags: image, angular

Is there a possibility to get the size of an Image i tried  following but my $event variable shows me an array

```
<img  src="image.png" (load)="dosomething($event)" />
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
  <img #img src="image.png" (load)="dosomething(img)" />
```

TS:

```
dosomething(img) {
  console.log(img.clientWidth, img.clientHeight);
}
```